# what are my options for handling this branch scenario?

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

I've created a new branch in VSTS off of the development branch.  I've pushed some changes to this branch.  I need to reset all of the changes I've made to this branch.  Preferably, I'd like to recreate the branch off of the latest develop branch.  What would be the easiest way for me to do this?  I'm using Visual Studio 2017 which is connected to VSTS (Visual Studio Team Services).  So I can perform source control actions through VS2017, vSTS or Git Bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've made a bunch of changes on `foo` and you want to reset `foo` to be where `develop` is right now:

```
git checkout foo
git reset develop --hard
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think the answer would be to simply overwrite the whole branch which the following url appears to address:

https://superuser.com/questions/716818/git-overwrite-branch-with-master